# Logging out of the asp.net site after the remember me checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ws-federation

I am using the WSFederationAuthentication module for authenticationin my site which in turn is using the Azure ACS. I can successfully login and logout of the system . We have our site setup so as soon as someone hits it and if they are not authenticated it transfers to a Secure Token Service website which does the authentication. The issue comes when I select the remember me checkbox checked and logout it logs me out and then tries to transfer me to the login page but it thinks I am already logged in and automatically logs me back in. I am thinking its not clearing the authentication cookies in or the information present in the header which does not get properly clear when I logout.

Can someone please look at the code and give me some idea on how to resolve this issue.

Note: It is only happening in IE . Firefox and Chrome are working as expected.

```
 WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            //clear local cookie
            authModule.SignOut(true);

            //  initiate federated sign out request to the STS
            SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(authModule.Issuer), authModule.Realm);
            String queryString = signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
            {
                return new RedirectResult(queryString);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Thanks